# Regex to find the link with all strings and a character anywhere in between

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've a text extract like this (the original text is very long with hyperlinks staggered across):

```
... <div> <a href=\n=3D"https://www.wonder.com/alerts/remove" style=3D"text-decoration:none;color:#427fed">Unsu=\nbscribe</a> <span style=3D"padding:0px 4px 0px 4px;color:#252525">|<a href=3D"https:=\n//www.wonder.com/url?rct=3Dj&amp;sa=3Dt&amp;></span> =\n<a href=3D"https://www.wonder.com/alerts?source=3Dalertsmail&amp;hl=3Den&=\namp;gl=3DIN&amp;msgid=3DMTA2MzYwOTAxMTQ5NzI4MTc3MTE" style=3D"text-decorati=\non:none;color:#427fed"> View all your alerts </a> </div> </td> </tr> <tr> <=\ntd style=3D"padding:6px 10px 0px 0px;font-family:Arial"> <a href=3D"https:/=\n/www.wonder.com/alerts/feeds/065638/93686812" styl=\ne=3D"text-decoration:none;color:#427fed">...
```

I'm trying to extract this hyperlink (not necessarily the last one): `https:/=\n/www.wonder.com/alerts/feeds/065638/93686812`

I do not know where the '=' will appear in the link. So tried to use a positive lookahead like this:

`re.match(r'(?=\=)\"https(.*).*\"', text)`

This did not help. Suggestions pls.

Also, is there a way we can define a list where the strings are present and then match a string that has all these strings? I saw couple of posts on matching any in the list, not all. I tried to look for a pattern like `(https)&(wonder)&(alerts)&(feeds)` but not much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this regex.

```
    https:(.*?)(>|")
```

You can test your regex online in this [link](https://regex101.com/)
I test your text with my regex and got 4 matchs.

Comment: Thanks. But am looking for the last link only.

Comment: @schmoozed so you can say the last index of output array.

Comment: I get that. But the text is more than a mb long and I don't want to capture all the links and the wanted link need not be the last one. So, Indexing doesn't help. The exact link needs to be captured.

Comment: @schmoozed do you want the latest link always?

Comment: nope. the link with https, wonder, alerts, feeds in it (such a link with these four strings is unique in the text though).

Comment: @schmoozed how about this regex?       (.*)"https:.*?wonder.*?alerts.*?feeds.*?("|>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172121/discussion-between-saeed-bolhasani-and-schmoozed).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
(\"https([^\"])*\d+\")
```